# Converting JPG image to Mat opencv UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java, opencv, mat, unsupportedoperation

I'm trying to convert a buffered image to a Matrix, but it throws an UnsupportedOperationException, which I have never seen before

```
public static Mat readMatImage(String path) {
    Mat mat = null;
    BufferedImage image;
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(new FileInputStream(path));
        mat = new Mat(image.getHeight(), image.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC3);
        byte[] data = ((DataBufferByte) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
        System.out.println(data[data.length - 1]);
        mat.put(0, 0, data);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return mat;
}
```

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Provided data element number (4000000) should be multiple of the Mat channels count (3)
> ```

Comment: Why don't you try reading the image with `cv::imread()`

Comment: I had originally done that, but it gave a NullPointerException

`public static Mat readMatImage(String path) {
  return Imgcodecs.imread(
    FileHandler.class.getClass().getResource(path).getPath()
    );
 }`

Comment: It means that your path is invalid, or the resource you want to access is not in correct formt.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider your read-image type because your image must be single channel and 8-bit to cast it to a mat element. If your image is RGB, try to convert it to binary image.